# getting a sub result from the same sql statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the next SQL statement:

```
SELECT xType0, xType1, xType2, SUM(xAmount) AS xxAmount FROM  (

                            SELECT 'Wared' AS xType0, 'Wared1' AS xType1,'Parent Payements' AS xType2, 
                            TheDate AS xDate, TheAmount AS xAmount, 
                            YEAR(TheDate) AS xYear, MONTH(TheDate) AS xMonth 
                            FROM tbl_parents_payments

                            UNION ALL

                            SELECT
                            CASE 
                            WHEN IncomeType = 'Wared' OR IncomeType = 'Deon Warda' THEN 'Wared'
                            WHEN IncomeType = 'Sader' OR IncomeType = 'Tsded' THEN 'Sader'
                            END AS xType0,
                            CASE 
                            WHEN IncomeType = 'Wared' THEN 'Wared1'
                            WHEN IncomeType = 'Sader' THEN 'Sader1'
                            WHEN IncomeType = 'Deon Warda' OR IncomeType = 'Tsded' THEN IncomeType
                            END AS xType1,
                            IncomeCatName AS xType2,
                            IncomeDate AS xDate, IncomeAmount AS xAmount, 
                            YEAR(IncomeDate) AS xYear, MONTH(IncomeDate) AS xMonth 
                            FROM tbl_income
                            INNER JOIN tbl_income_cat ON tbl_income.IncomeCat = tbl_income_cat.IncomeCatID

                            UNION ALL

                            SELECT 'Sader' AS xType0, 'Sader1' AS xType1,'' AS xType2, 
                            TheDate AS xDate, TheAmount AS xAmount, 
                            YEAR(TheDate) AS xYear, MONTH(TheDate) AS xMonth 
                            FROM tbl_teachers_payments

                            UNION ALL

                            SELECT 'Sader' AS xType0, 'Mashobat' AS xType1, ThePartner AS xType2, 
                            TheDate AS xDate, TheAmount AS xAmount, 
                            YEAR(TheDate) AS xYear, MONTH(TheDate) AS xMonth 
                            FROM tbl_partners_payments


                            ) maintbl
                            WHERE xDate BETWEEN @Date1 AND @Date2
                            GROUP BY xType0, xType1, xType2
```

by that SQL statement I get the values between 2 dates that called (xxAmount), my question is how to use the same **sub** SQL statement to get the values less than a specified date to be (xxxAmount)??

how to use "**maintbl**" again with new condition.??

Comment: Simplify! [mcve]

Comment: @jarlh actually, I just want to know how I can use the sub SQL, making an example is not easy because I have about 4 tables to get the data from them

Comment: @jarlh  how to use "**maintbl**" again with new condition.??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT xType0, xType1, xType2, xMonth, xYear, xAmount FROM (
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN TheDate < '2021-01-01' THEN 'Wared Sabiq'
        WHEN TheDate > '2021-01-31' THEN 'Wared Lahik'    
        WHEN TheDate BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-31' THEN 'Wared1'
    END AS xType0,
    CASE
        WHEN TheDate < '2021-01-01' THEN 'Wared1'
        WHEN TheDate > '2021-01-31' THEN 'Wared2'    
        WHEN TheDate BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-31' THEN 'Wared2'
    END AS xType1,
    'Payment' AS xType2, 
    TheDate AS xDate, SUM(TheAmount) AS xAmount, 
    YEAR(TheDate) AS xYear, MONTH(TheDate) AS xMonth 
    FROM tbl_parents_payments
    GROUP BY xType0, xType1, xType2, xMonth, xYear

UNION ALL

SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN (IncomeType = 'Wrd' OR IncomeType = 'Wareda') AND IncomeDate < '2021-01-01' THEN 'Wared Sabiq'
        WHEN (IncomeType = 'Wrd' OR IncomeType = 'Wareda') AND IncomeDate > '2021-01-31' THEN 'Wared Lahik'
        WHEN (IncomeType = 'Wrd' OR IncomeType = 'Wareda') AND IncomeDate BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-31' THEN 'Wared1'
        WHEN (IncomeType = 'sdr' OR IncomeType = 'Wareda tas') AND IncomeDate < '2021-01-01' THEN 'Sadir Sabik'
        WHEN (IncomeType = 'sdr' OR IncomeType = 'Wareda tas') AND IncomeDate > '2021-01-31' THEN 'Sadir Lahik'
        WHEN (IncomeType = 'sdr' OR IncomeType = 'Wareda tas') AND IncomeDate BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-31' THEN 'Sader2'
    END AS xType0,
    CASE 
        WHEN (IncomeType = 'Wrd') AND IncomeDate < '2021-01-01' THEN 'Wared2'
        WHEN (IncomeType = 'Wrd') AND IncomeDate > '2021-01-31' THEN 'Wared2'
        WHEN (IncomeType = 'Wrd') AND IncomeDate BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-31' THEN 'Wared2'
        WHEN (IncomeType = 'sdr') AND IncomeDate < '2021-01-01' THEN 'Sader1'
        WHEN (IncomeType = 'sdr') AND IncomeDate > '2021-01-31' THEN 'Sader1'
        WHEN (IncomeType = 'sdr') AND IncomeDate BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-31' THEN 'Sader2'
        WHEN (IncomeType = 'Wareda' OR IncomeType = 'Wareda tas') AND IncomeDate < '2021-01-01' THEN CONCAT(IncomeType, ' sabik')
        WHEN (IncomeType = 'Wareda' OR IncomeType = 'Wareda tas') AND IncomeDate > '2021-01-31' THEN CONCAT(IncomeType, ' Lahik')
        WHEN (IncomeType = 'Wareda' OR IncomeType = 'Wareda tas') AND IncomeDate BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-31' THEN                     CONCAT(IncomeType, ' tm')
    END AS xType1,
    IncomeCatName AS xType2,
    IncomeDate AS xDate, IncomeAmount AS xAmount, 
    YEAR(IncomeDate) AS xYear, MONTH(IncomeDate) AS xMonth 
    FROM tbl_income
    INNER JOIN tbl_income_cat ON tbl_income.IncomeCat = tbl_income_cat.IncomeCatID
    GROUP BY xType0, xType1, xType2, xMonth, xYear
    
UNION ALL

SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN TheDate < '2021-01-01' THEN 'Sadir Sabik'
        WHEN TheDate > '2021-01-31' THEN 'Sadir Lahik'    
        WHEN TheDate BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-31' THEN 'tm'
    END AS xType0,
    CASE
        WHEN TheDate < '2021-01-01' THEN 'tm'
        WHEN TheDate > '2021-01-31' THEN 'tm'    
        WHEN TheDate BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-31' THEN 'Sader2'
    END AS xType1,
    'ttm' AS xType2, 
    TheDate AS xDate, SUM(TheAmount) AS xAmount, 
    YEAR(TheDate) AS xYear, MONTH(TheDate) AS xMonth 
    FROM tbl_teachers_payments
    GROUP BY xType0, xType1, xType2, xMonth, xYear
    
UNION ALL

SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN TheDate < '2021-01-01' THEN 'Sadir Sabik'
        WHEN TheDate > '2021-01-31' THEN 'Sadir Lahik'    
        WHEN TheDate BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-31' THEN 'tm'
    END AS xType0,
    CASE
        WHEN TheDate < '2021-01-01' THEN 'mashobat'
        WHEN TheDate > '2021-01-31' THEN 'mashobat'    
        WHEN TheDate BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-31' THEN 'mashobat'
    END AS xType1,
    ThePartner AS xType2, 
    TheDate AS xDate, SUM(TheAmount) AS xAmount, 
    YEAR(TheDate) AS xYear, MONTH(TheDate) AS xMonth 
    FROM tbl_partners_payments
    GROUP BY xType0, xType1, xType2, xMonth, xYear
    
) xmaintbl

ORDER BY xType0 ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

You could stored all your unions results into a CTE(Common table expression), then use your different conditions next. and choose your desired result in the end. for example

```
;WITH maintbl AS
(
    SELECT 'Wared' AS xType0, 'Wared1' AS xType1,'Parent Payements' AS xType2, 
    TheDate AS xDate, TheAmount AS xAmount, 
    YEAR(TheDate) AS xYear, MONTH(TheDate) AS xMonth 
    FROM tbl_parents_payments

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
    CASE 
    WHEN IncomeType = 'Wared' OR IncomeType = 'Deon Warda' THEN 'Wared'
    WHEN IncomeType = 'Sader' OR IncomeType = 'Tsded' THEN 'Sader'
    END AS xType0,
    CASE 
    WHEN IncomeType = 'Wared' THEN 'Wared1'
    WHEN IncomeType = 'Sader' THEN 'Sader1'
    WHEN IncomeType = 'Deon Warda' OR IncomeType = 'Tsded' THEN IncomeType
    END AS xType1,
    IncomeCatName AS xType2,
    IncomeDate AS xDate, IncomeAmount AS xAmount, 
    YEAR(IncomeDate) AS xYear, MONTH(IncomeDate) AS xMonth 
    FROM tbl_income
    INNER JOIN tbl_income_cat ON tbl_income.IncomeCat = tbl_income_cat.IncomeCatID

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 'Sader' AS xType0, 'Sader1' AS xType1,'' AS xType2, 
    TheDate AS xDate, TheAmount AS xAmount, 
    YEAR(TheDate) AS xYear, MONTH(TheDate) AS xMonth 
    FROM tbl_teachers_payments

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 'Sader' AS xType0, 'Mashobat' AS xType1, ThePartner AS xType2, 
    TheDate AS xDate, TheAmount AS xAmount, 
    YEAR(TheDate) AS xYear, MONTH(TheDate) AS xMonth 
    FROM tbl_partners_payments
),
DateBetween AS
(
    SELECT xType0, xType1, xType2, SUM(xAmount) AS xxAmount 
    FROM
    manitbl
    WHERE xDate BETWEEN @Date1 AND @Date2
    GROUP BY xType0, xType1, xType2
),
DateBefore AS
(
    SELECT xType0, xType1, xType2, SUM(xAmount) AS xxAmount 
    FROM
    manitbl
    WHERE xDate <= @Date1
    GROUP BY xType0, xType1, xType2
)
SELECT * FROM DateBefore ----DateBetween
```

Comment: when I use "WITH", it gives me an error "Unrecognized statement type"

Comment: are you using SQL SERVER?

Comment: ok, after mysql version 8 support CTE. if you're in older version, what about to stored all your union into a temp table or table variable, then use them to join as a normal table.

Comment: sorry bro, can you explain more please

Comment: it's like CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Temp
SELECT 'Wared' AS xType0... 
UNION ALL.....
UNION ALL... then use the temp table to do your query

Comment: ok I created but how to use this table to make 2 queries at the same time?

Comment: when you say at the same time, do you want to show two result in one dataset? otherwise just execute twice or select both 2 querys and execute once.

Comment: I want to filter the temp table to get 2 results with 2 conditions at the same time as you mentioned in "with statement"

Comment: Bro, can't do it even when you use CTE, you still only get 1 result at same, if you want to get another result, you need to change CTEName from DateBefore to DateBetween. Another option is to add another colum 'Status' and use case statement like  SELECT xType0, xType1, xType2, SUM(xAmount) AS xxAmount, CASE WHEN xDate =< @Date1 THEN 'Before' ELSE 'Between' END AS Status
 FROM
 manitbl
 WHERE xDate <= Date2
 GROUP BY xType0, xType1, xType2

Comment: thank you bro you gave me a good tip to find the solution, thank you so much, I will prepare it and put it here, thank you

Comment: Any luck on that? XD